# More pythonic way for a conditional variable

Tags: python, if-statement

This is what I am trying to do:

1. Get few arguments
2. Based on the arguments, form a string
3. Return the string

However, for this, I could see 3 potential ways:

```
def form_statement(subject, verb, object):
    greetings = ""
    if subject in ("Paul", "Raj"):
        greetings = "mister"
    return "%s %s %s %s" % (subject, verb, object, greetings)
```

Second way of doing this is:

```
def form_statement(subject, verb, object):
    if subject in ("Paul", "Raj"):
        greetings = "mister"
    else:
        greetings = ""
    return "%s %s %s %s" % (subject, verb, object, greetings)
```

And third way is:

```
def form_statement(subject, verb, object):
    greetings = "mister" if subject in ("Paul", "Raj") else ""
    return "%s %s %s %s" % (subject, verb, object, greetings)
```

Is there any other better way to do something like this? Right now I am opting for the first way as the "processing" to get the greetings string is a function in itself and makes the line to go beyond 80 characters when third way is used.

EDIT: It seems some one is confused that I am asking which one is better to use(as they voted this for opinion-based). Here, I am trying to find whether there is a better way to do and gave examples of what are the things I could think off so that others may not give them as answers. And as mentioned in one of the answers, I find using dictionary is better for me in a similar case.

Comment: All solutions look good. First is "safe", as you always get some value to `greetings`. 2nd is easier to read, with more complex logic you cold forget setting value to `greetings` and get undefined variable error in last statement. Last one I like the most, safe, still well readable, short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One pythonic way is using a dictionary for preserving the subjects with their relative `greetings` and then use `dict.get()` method that also accepts a second argument which will be returns if the key is missed in your dictionary.

```
main_dict = {"Paul":"mister", "Raj": "mister"}

def form_statement(main_dict, subject, verb, object):
    greetings = main_dict.get(subject, '')
    return "{} {} {} {}".format(subject, verb, object, greetings)
```

This approach will show its power when you are dealing with larger datasets. Because the dictionaries use hash table and their indexing order is O(1). And also you can use different results for each verb.

Comment: a typo with the function's first argument as `subjects`. It should be `subject`. A good way to use dictionary.

Comment: Also, I think it should be `subjects.get(subject, '')`

Comment: @thiruvenkadam I thought you are check the member ship of the `verb` in tuple. Check the edit.

Comment: @tobias_k Yeah, Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The first version makes two assignments to `greetings` when the condition is true.

The other two versions are equivalent. 
As a general rule the more readable one should be used. 
Remember, the developer's time is a valuable resource. 
That's why I would say the  The `if-else` construct is always appropriate and the ternary conditional (`A if cond else B`) is good for a one-liner.

If you are enhancing an existing code, preserve its style.

---

BTW, the fastest lookup is achieved with a set: `name in {"Paul", .... }`

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically create a dictionary from all the names that should have a "mister", and names that should have similar titles. Then, just `get` the value from that dictionary, or `""` as default in case the name is not present.

```
pairings = [(("Paul", "Raj"), "mister"), (("Anna", "Paula"), "madam")]
greetings = {name: title for names, title in pairings for name in names}

def form_statement(subject, verb, object):
    return "%s %s %s %s" % (subject, verb, object, greetings.get(subject, ""))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may consider function arguments as list and concatenate them with spaces. As `args` comes as tuple, it has to be converted to list first.

```
def form_statement(*args):
    args = list(args)
    if args[0] in ["Paul", "Raj"]:
        args.append("mister")
    return " ".join(args)
```

Here is my small test suite (stored in the same file as function above and run via `$ py.test greet.py`:

```
def test_paul():
    assert form_statement("Paul", "get", "well") == "Paul get well mister"


def test_raj():
    assert form_statement("Raj", "get", "well") == "Raj get well mister"


def test_else():
    assert form_statement("John", "get", "well") == "John get well"
```

**EDIT**: Added a bit more explicit version:

as @thiruvenkadam correctly noted, the original version was not very explicit. Here is a bit improved version of the function.

```
def form_statement(subject, verb, object):
    if subject in ["Paul", "Raj"]:
        return " ".join([subject, verb, object, "mister"])
    else:
        return " ".join([subject, verb, object])
```

Small advantage of both implementations above is, there are no trailing spaces
present.

Comment: I am not too convinced about this approach. "Explicit is better than Implicit".

Comment: @thiruvenkadam Thanks. You are correct. (this feedback is what I like on SO answers). I added a bit more explicit version.